# How to make redis + node.js code easier to read?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, redis

I would like to use redis and node.js to verify the users' log-in data of my website.

Here's a sample code of what I'm doing now

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

var userID = 'aaa';
var password = '123456';

client.sadd('userIDs', userID, redis.print);
client.hset('id2password', userID, password, redis.print);

client.sismember('userIDs', userID, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    if(result == 1) {
        client.hget('id2password', userID, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            if(result == password) {
                console.log('All data are correct.');
            } else {
                console.log('Wrong password.');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(userID + ' doesn\'t exist.');
    }
});
```

For me, this code is difficult to read. Because all the things I want to do after the "if" statement are wrapped inside a callback function. How can I make it easier to read?

I wish my code can be rewritten like this.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

var userID = 'aaa';
var password = '123456';

client.sadd('userIDs', userID, redis.print);
client.hset('id2password', userID, password, redis.print);

if(mySismember('userIDs', userID)) {
    if(myHget('id2password', userID) == password) {
        console.log('All data are correct.');
    } else {
        console.log('Wrong password.');
    }
} else {
    console.log(userID + ' doesn\'t exist.');
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this goal?

I know that the commands in redis are executed asynchronously. It looks like that using callback functions is unavoidable in this situation.

Comment: You should have a look at promises. See [What are promises and why should I use them?](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them)

Comment: is this kind of a codereview.stackexchange question?

Comment: @bitoiu At it's current state, I think it is better of here at Stack Overflow. The OP has a specific goal for how the desired result should be, in terms of how the code should look, and wants to know if that is achievable.

Comment: @bitoiu only if OP includes his real code instead of an example. =;)-

Comment: I read this "Here's a sample code of what I'm doing now" as a sample of his code :=)